# Are there any public UDDI registries available?

Tags: web-services, uddi, webservice-discovery

I am currently trying to get a grasp of UDDI and would like to run some examples with the inquiry API, but I can’t find public registries that I can query with my SOAP messages.

IBM, Microsoft and SAP used to host public UDDI servers a couple of years ago but that was discontinued.

I know [xmethods](http://www.xmethods.com/ve2/index.po) contains a list of publicly available web services, but I would like to concentrate only on discovery of web services with UDDI (and not really call the services afterwards).

Does anyone know of any public UDDI registries available?

Comment: I was under the impression that UDDI had been deprecated? Anyone?

Comment: If the thing is deprecated why has jUDDI implemented version 3 of the specs in June this year?

Comment: Maybe they implemented version 3 of the UDDI spec because their name is j**UDDI**?

Comment: "Maybe they implemented version 3 of the UDDI spec because their name is j**UDDI**?". I never thought of it that way, but you do make an interesting point. Nonetheless, the question still remains; are there any public UDDI registries available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be better installing [jUDDI](http://ws.apache.org/juddi/) or something if this is just for learning and experimentation.

Although my feeling is that this particular standard has never really taken off and probably never will. There must be a reason that the public registries operated by large organisations have been shut down. Just a thought, before you commit too much time and effort to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. jUDDI is my second option. I would first like to use some concrete metadata not publish some of mine and then retrieve it (a real thing I think is more useful than a “Hello Word” UDDI thing).

Comment: Yeah -- I see what you are saying. That would be more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Even if there are public UDDI registries, the question is whether anyone looks in those registries when using a web service. I think that the answer is "no".

Comment: Ok, I understand that no one uses a UDDI registry to lookup web services to call (heck... I even stated in my question that I don’t want to call the service afterwards) but I do want to interact with a <b>real</b> UDDI registry. I can’t imagine that only IBM, Microsoft and SAP used to provide such registries and when they picked up their toys and left, the entire UDDI movement stopped.

Comment: They _were_ the UDDI movement.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Microsoft, IBM and SAP shut down their public UDDI back in 2007.

seekda (http://webservices.seekda.com/) is a search engine for public Web Services (although it is not UDDI based).

Comment: Service is down.

Answer (score 1):

UDDI version 3 dates from 2002 (http://www.uddi.org/pubs/uddi-v3.00-published-20020719.htm) and the OASIS committee that defined it has been disbanded. So if a new version of jUDDI supports it, that doesn't mean there's any action on the specification.

Answer (score 0):

The jUDDI project maintains a public UDDI server for testing purposes. If you're just looking to learn, have fun.

http://uddi-jbossoverlord.rhcloud.com/

Of course, you can just download jUDDI and run it locally as well.