# Finding Web services by functionalities

Tags: web-services, service-discovery, uddi

I want to find many functionality similar services, and when one service failed, I could switched to the other.

Is there a repository where I could find Web services, using functionality e.g., weather forecasting?

(I heard that UDDI seems to be deprecated, but I cannot confirm for that)

Comment: I can confirm it for you. Nobody uses UDDI, and nobody ever did.

Comment: Furthermore, if you work your use case all the way through, you'll learn _why_ nobody ever used UDDI. Once you've discovered a set of "similar" services, how, exactly, will you use them? If the services have identical WSDLs, and if they serve identical data in the identical environment, then maybe you could switch between them. Otherwise, what exactly are you going to do?

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for the reply, how to tweak for each services which may have potentially input/output could be done by the developers, the keypoint of the questions is that, where to find those services? is there a public database that has good coverage for existing services?

Comment: Work the problem through. Assume there is such a public database. Now, how, exactly, will you use it? How will you decide whether two services are equivalent, so that you could call one or the other? The fact is, the entire idea just simply does not work. That is why there is no  public database to suit your needs - it is simply not possible to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

@Bogdan - The Apache jUDDI project actually put up two instances:

- one for demo, for which there is no guarantee your data will stay around, but it's nice to play around with it. Find the link for it at the landing page of the prod instance (it only allows me to post two links)
- one for (semi) demo production purposes for which you can request a user account, and data is guaranteed to stay around. You can find it at: https://www.webserviceregistry.com. If you want the certificate to match the address then use: https://uddi-jbossoverlord.rhcloud.com, which is a less catchy address to the same instance.

Cheers,

--Kurt

Answer (score 0):

There was only one notable public UDDI registry (put in place by IBM, Microsoft and SAP) but that has long been discontinued. If you are to find a public registry it will probably be something set up just for demonstrative purposes (e.g. [jUDDI demo](http://uddi-jbossoverlord.rhcloud.com/home.jsp)).

@JohnSaunders is right, nobody uses UDDI in the wild. [Public repositories are not practical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525045/is-the-public-uddi-movement-dead-or-was-it-ever-alive/13333964#13333964) while the private ones are most of the time unnecessary, providing for a complex solution to a simple problem.

You should find (and evaluate) a few stable web services and have their endpoints in a configuration file of some sort. Call one of the services and on failure go for the others you have configured.

If on the other hand you insist on going the UDDI route, then create your own private repository and use that because you won't find a public one (others - me included - have tried and got out empty handed).

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, yes UDDI does support this kind of query. Basically, you'd want to use a "Inquiry API" method "Find_service", passing in a CategoryBag/keyReference that matches a known pattern for weather services with some wildcards to help you get results. In addition, you'll need a find_qualifier for approximateMatch to enable the wildcards. Part of the issue is that UDDI allows registrants to use the spec in many different ways and thus this example assumes that there is in fact a standardized way to register and tag a service as providing weather information. It's up to the governance process of the organization hosting the uddi node.

"@JohnSaunders is right, nobody uses UDDI in the wild" - talk about a blanket statement. Perhaps you both meant "few people", but to say "nobody" without being able to prove it is silly.

"(I heard that UDDI seems to be deprecated, but I cannot confirm for that)". Widely used? probably not. Deprecated? Apache, Microsoft, IBM, HP, Oracle, and WS02 still sell or give away implementations of UDDI so I wouldn't exactly call it deprecated.

Comment: Saying that nobody uses UDDI in the wild might be a blanket statement, but I can't say "few people" either because there is no public UDDI registry. You can off course find web services with a certain functionality using UDDI, the question is: Where?