# UDDI role in webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, uddi

I have heard folks using the acronym UDDI in the context of web services but I am not clear what role it plays in web services. I have gone through the book *Java Web Services Up and Running* by Martin Kalin and it hardly mentions UDDI anywhere.

As per my understanding from the net:

> UDDI (Universal Description, Discovery, and Integration) is an
>   XML-based registry for businesses worldwide to list themselves on the
>   Internet. It helps companies to find one another on the Web and call
>   their services. Basically, with UDDI, companies can register/describe
>   their web services on the Internet so that other companies can find
>   their WSDL and generate stubs out of it.

Is that correct? Say I am the producer of a web service which is for a limited set of users. I don’t have to register with UDDI, because I can give them a WSDL URL manually. Correct?

Is UDDI essentially a service similar to Google Search where a consumer can search web services based on some keywords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is UUDI essentially a service similar to a Google search where a consumer can search webservices based on some keywords?

Basically yes, although the analogy most commonly used was that of "[yellow pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration#Structure)" of web services.

> ... say I am producer of some web service which is for limited set of users, I don't have to register with UDDI? I can give them a WSDL url manually. Correct?

If you provide a service for a limited number of clients (i.e. the service is not public) you can just give them the WSDL or a link to it.

UDDI nowadays makes sense inside businesses that are built on top of a service oriented architecture, where UDDI is good for having a centralized place of registering and locating web services. But a public UDDI existed mainly as an experiment for reasons explained here: [Is the public UDDI movement dead or, was it ever alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525045/is-the-public-uddi-movement-dead-or-was-it-ever-alive/)

Comment: @Bgdan. Thanks. But i did not get how "UDDI makes sense inside businesses that are built on top of a service oriented architecture" ? I mean how SOA and UDDI are linked here ?

Comment: @emilly: UDDI is a tool you can use while building a service oriented architecture, a tool just like SOAP, REST, ESB, WSDL, etc. UDDI is a component, or an implementation detail, used when you have a service oriented architecture. You can of course use UDDI without adopting SOA, but if you just have a service or two, using UDDI might be more trouble than it's worth.