# Web service recommendation, what and why?

Tags: web-services

I just read a great [article](http://alistapart.com/article/webservices) on web services by Patrick Cooney at AListApart. However, something is still vague to me on why web service recommendation is important and how it works? Is this approach an alternative for UDDI and similar solutions?

Comment: Here is a stackoverflow article explaining UDDI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315491/uddi-role-in-webservices

Comment: [What questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDDI provides the infrastructure for web service discovery. As the linked article from the comment says, it is basically the "yellow pages" for web services.

If I understand your reference to "web service recommendation" correctly, you mean a system that, given a list of equivalent candidate services, chooses the best one for you, probably based on matching a set of requirements against some kind of QoS metrics of these services.

Therefore, such a system can be used as either an addition to UDDI (if the consumer performs the basic discovery and only delegates the dynamic selection to the recommendation system) or replace it transparently for the consumer (the consumer asks the recommendation system for a service type with some given QoS parameters). In the second case, the recommendation system would use UDDI for discovery and then filter the answer for the consumer based on the QoS parameters.