# Why in SOAP client needs to know the web services's interface?

Tags: soap, soap-client

I am new to web application development, I am learning many things from many tutorial, currently I am learning SOAP and REST.
My confusion is regarding SOAP , in  SOAP based architecture when a user enters a URL, it takes him/her to SOAP client and then that is the page that the client sees ? and then this SOAP-client will actually communicate to another application SOAP server ??

Not understanding it at all? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Where does a user enter a URL in SOAP? Since [UDDI is dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525045/is-the-public-uddi-movement-dead-or-was-it-ever-alive) one can look up the endpoints, available methods and schema from the WSDL, which a client can use to create stub-classes for further usage, via the Web. In most languages (and frameworks) you have to pregenerate artifacts though beforehand. It is possible though rarely done to dynamically lookup endpoints and service methods from the WSDL directly and invoke a service without having to use stub-classes first.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is meant for communication between machine over HTTP/HTTPS with common interoperable format i.e XML.

Think like you are payment gateway provider,  someone's would like to use your payment gateway for transactions.

So as payment gateway provider, you may create webservice,  and whoever wants to use it could create SOAP client to use your payment gateway service.

So in your case the HTML page is party would like to utilise the payment gateway service (by calling the SOAP service).

Do some googling, you will find lots of practical SOAP use cases.